# I am not able to import and use numpy in my python shell

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

I have installed NLTK with Python and the tokenising and tagging part is working fine but I'm unable to work on `Numpy` as I'm getting the error which says:

> ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

[This image contains the screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5q6V.jpg)

Comment: Did you install NumPy?

Comment: Yes I did install but I couldn't import it.

Comment: Which method (package manager, pip, setup.py,...) did you use to build and and install numpy and nltk for  python3.5? State the full command line, please (if applicable).

Comment: I installed nltk from http://www.nltk.org/install.html and then I imported nltk and used the command nltk.download() to install all the packages still I'm not able to run numpy on python shell.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the correct interpreter (2.x vs. 3.x)? Did you install numpy for 2 or 3 using pip2 or pip3? Typically pip will be assigned to whatever your default interpreter is. Double check with `pip --version`, also check if numpy is installed with `pip list`.

As an aside, you might want to look at the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), has numpy and all the required stuff for practically any science or data oriented operations you can think of.

Comment: I haven't installed pip. Do I need to install it before importing numpy ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need pip, but it is incredibly handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 versions of python (2.x and 3.x), probably the command "python" has an alias or a symbolic link to the most recent version (3.x) and something similar occurs with "pip" command.

Maybe you have 2 versions of pip: pip (pip3) and pip2.
So, to install numpy you need to run: sudo pip2 install numpy (it will install numpy for python2)

Comment: I haven't installed pip. Do I need to install it before importing numpy ?

Comment: How did you installed Numpy? Not necessarely. Pip is a useful tool to install packages for python.